# Can anyone explain this high-frequency "alien voodoo black magic"?

Tags: high-frequency, spectrum-analyzer

I was casually [watching Mike tear down a spectrum analyser](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eyA2lWQrxwg) (13:30 is the relevant part, 16:50 is the awesome part), and he came across what he aptly described as "weird messed up alien voodoo black magic stuff":

[image: High Frequency Voodoo]

As a layman, I can only nod in agreement with his description. Do we have any sufficiently experienced alien-voodooologists around to explain what this madness is all about?

Comment: Are we looking at the wiggly bits to the left, or the triangular bits to the right (or both)?

Comment: Another question about similar weird stuff http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/33369/3552

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think this blog post answers your question pretty well :)

[Demystifying RF Circuit Design – The art of Voodoo](http://jaunty-electronics.com/blog/2012/10/demystifying-rf-circuit-design-the-art-of-voodoo/)

In short, the 3 main components illustrated are:

- hair-pin type band-pass filter
- distributed element low-pass filter (regularly-spaced rectangles 'dumbells')
- series LC resonator (the radial stubs off one side of the trace)

See the referring page for details about how they work, and which-is-which.

Comment: Right answer, but [little more than a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: @NewAlexandria's edits made it better ;)

Answer (score 10):

This is actually something I stumbled apon not that long ago.
Here is what it is.

[Distributed element filter - WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_element_filter)

It has examples almost identical to those in the video.